# ACM: Create pattern given puzzle shape

Tags: algorithm

I'm preparing for the ACM competition in my country and I'm pretty stuck with this problem, I don't know what algorithm to use either...

**The problem is:**
Given a puzzle pattern you need to tell if it can be constructed only by using pieces with the pieces that have L-shape (as shown on the right image below).
[image]
<sub>(source: [mendo.mk](http://mendo.mk/task_files/puzzle.png))</sub>

So in this example answer is YES because pattern in the left can be constructed by this piece. Pieces are always the same, pattern is given in the input.

Here are the constraints

```
Input  
The first line of input contains one positive integer T (1 <= T
 <= 100), the number of test cases.

Each test case starts with a line that contains two integers H and W
(1 <= H, W <= 500), which represent the height and width of the grid
containing the pattern. The following H lines, each containing W
characters, denote the grid. Each character is either 'R' (red), 'W'
(white) or '.' (empty space). Each grid contains at least one 'R' or
'W' character.  

Output  
For each test case, on a separate line, output either 'YES' if
it is possible to construct the pattern with the puzzle pieces, or
'NO' otherwise.

Constraints  
Time limit: 15 seconds  
Memory limit: 64 megabytes
```

Example

```
input                output
2                    NO
3 3                  YES
W.. 
RW.  
WRW  
3 4  
RWW.  
WWRW  
..WR
```

Comment: Would this work? I can't imagine a counterexample. If anything, it should greatly reduce the complexity in many cases. -- Say you introduce another 'temporary' puzzle shape: `BW`. Iteratively remove all `W`s with only one adjacent non-white tile, and 1) if the non-white tile is `R`, turn it into `B`, or 2) if the non-white tile is `B`, remove it. When your iteration doesn't change anything, look at the board: answer YES if it's empty, answer NO otherwise.

Comment: @Rhymoid: If the original grid was WRW, wouldn't your algorithm report YES?

Comment: Good point, @ScottHunter! I completely missed that :) But I think this idea could still work if modified, albeit in a more complicated way. You'd need four additional colours instead of one: `WRW` would become `1W`, where `1` can only be removed with a `1` above or below it.

Answer (score 3):

1. You know if there are N red spots, there must be 2N white spots.
2. Each red spot locates a L-shape; you just have to determine the orientations
3. Some L-shapes will have a more limited number of choices than others (for example, red spot in a corner can only have an L with 1 orientation).  If you "place" the pieces in order by how many possible orientations they have (small to big), you can limit the number of possibilities to be considered.
4. If the pattern is (or becomes) disjoint, you can solve each of the disconnected sections independently in some sequence (as opposed to bouncing between sections).  Might not be worth the effort to detect such occurrences, although if you could *place* pieces to *cause* such divisions, that could help speed things up.

Comment: If i understand you correctly you are suggesting kind of a brute-force approach. If there is 500x500 input, there could be around 8000 pieces, first piece can be placed in 4 ways, second in 4 ways...last in 4 ways lets say you manage to reduce 8000 pieces to 1000 that you dont know what there position is that is still 4^^1000  ways which can never be solved in reasonable time.

Comment: I think that brute force, on the average case, doesn't need to take that much power if you use something like depth-first search. The decision tree may be truncated really early on.

Comment: @Rhymoid This is not a brute force problem.  There is no way, even with optimizations, pruning, truncating, branch+bound, etc. that you can run an exponential brute force algorithm on a 500x500 grid.

Comment: @CaptainCodeman You seem to be very sure of this. Any evidence or proof?

Comment: @Rhymoid With all due respect, in my opinion your claim is more outrageous than mine so it seems the burden of proof should be on you: You are claiming that an O(4^n) exponential algorithm where n=80,000 will complete in a reasonable amount of time.  Even if 99.9999999999999999% of nodes get truncated your running time is still longer than the age of the universe.

Comment: @CaptainCodeman Furthermore (and I didn't mention this), I suspect that, on the average case, a problem of that size may be expected to become very disjoint (these subproblems can be solved independently, turning multiplied time complexity into added). I suspect that detecting this is not too expensive, and that with a proper selection strategy, you can even force this to happen (instantiate the red tiles near the diagonal first, and you've separated the problem into an upper and lower triangle; you can do something similar for both triangles).

Comment: @CaptainCodeman (I'm not sure if one would still call this brute force, though ;))

Comment: @Rhymoid Trust me, it won't work.  Have you written many brute-force tile covering problems?  They tend to break down after about 10x10 or 20x20.  500x500 is just ridiculous.  The only way I can see it working is if you manage to implement sufficient optimizations to your brute force to make the algorithm essentially the same as the polynomial 2-SAT algorithm I described, at which point the algorithm is no longer brute force.

Answer (score 2):

In the general case, this would be a brute force problem unsolvable for this size, but the hint is that they've given you an additional constraint (the red square) which actually simplifies the problem.

This is a [2-SAT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2-satisfiability) problem, for which there is a very simple textbook algorithm.

The trick is to model the problem as a 2-SAT problem.  Basically, if you notice, once you place an "L-shape" on a red square, you have 2 independent options:

- You can choose to occupy the square to the left OR the square to the right of the red square.
- You can choose to occupy the square immediately above or below the red square.

These are both independent, and they can each be represented by a binary variable.  From there, you see where there are collisions with possible nearby red squares, and form binary logic statements, which you then feed into your 2-SAT solver.

Note that you will also need to do some additional checks, e.g. the number of white squares must be exactly twice the number of red squares in each connected component.

Answer (score 0):

I think a reasonable approach would be using [memoization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) .

Here is an algorithm :-

> 1. select a position to place L.
> 2. recursively evaluate the next configuration of puzzle by erasing the positions occupied.
> 3. store result of recursive call in hashmap  hash(Grid) => true/false, The hashmap store whether the puzzle configuration is solvable of not.
> 4. After a new call check whether the call is already done in hashmap if so directly return result from hashmap.

Comment: If OP was worried about the TIME it takes to cover the possibilities, the SPACE to store them would surely be more of a problem.

Comment: @ScottHunter There are not as many possibilities as the red marks are only places that can have the L shaped pieces.

Comment: @ScottHunter Make a symmetric hash function might help as well. Like the mirror images of the same grid would have same hash function

Comment: But aren't you storing ALL potential configurations?  (OP seems to think there could be thousands of "red marks", and you're storing combinations of piece placements, unless I misread your proposal.)  And mirror images only gets you a small constant factor reduction.

Comment: @ScottHunter I think there is lot of symmetry in the lot of configurations generated by this environment and the constant factor that you are saying is actually reducing lot of branching of recursion so it contributes to higher reduction then you think.

Comment: @ScottHunter If there is problem in space complexity then you can always remove a value from hashmap after it is reused to prevent hash table from growing. This trick might increase the time but not by much.